# Best practice for class with many member variables

Tags: c++, class-design, root-framework

**short question:**
If you must have many (even more than 200) member variables (each of them will be a plot of some physical quantity of interest in our analysis). What is the best place where to declare these variables?

**long explanation:**
The framework I use for my analysis creates a class to loop over events, it can be narrowed down to

```
constructor()
initialize()
execute()
finalize()
```

In the header you would declare pointers like (this is apparently a requirement of the `ROOT` package we must use):

```
std::vector<double> *m_jet_pt;
```

and pointer to a histogram class:

```
TH1F *h_jet_pt;
```

then in the `constructor` one must initialize the pointers to some definite memory address (as far as I understand this is for later read data from a file)

```
constructor()
{
  // this is data, will be associated to a TTree later
  m_jet_pt = 0;

  // this is a histogram
  h_jet_pt = new TH1F("name", "title", nbins, min_bin, max_bin); 
}
```

then in the `initialize` function you open a file containing data previously stored and set the address of the members of the class to point to objects contained in the file (I don't know how this works or if my statement is precise):

```
TFile *file = new TFile("filename.root");

// The tree is where the data is (for some reason ROOT uses C style casts)
TTree *tree = (TTree*)file->Get("MyTree");

// this is how to set the address of the member class pointer
// to point to the data in the tree:
tree->SetBranchAddress("m_jet_pt", &jet_pt);
```

Then in the `execute` function is called in a loop, once for each event and you would do the physics selection you want

```
execute()
{
  // I omit here where the `i` index comes from as not relevant
  if(m_jet_pt->at(i) > 30)

    h_jet_pt->Fill();
}
```

and finally in the `finalize` function you would do all you need to do once each event after the selection is made, for example storing the histograms in another file

```
finalize()
{
  h_jet_pt->Write();
}
```

Now immagine I have 20 quantites for `jets`, 30 for `electrons`, 30 for `muons` and so on, you can see how the number of member variables gets huge! Soon the code becames a mess so how would you expert programmers deal with such a situation? Hope this is clear enough!

Comment: if the data is the same type use a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: why not make thing like `jet` have it's own class?

Comment: _"If you must have many (even more than 200) member variables ..."_ That's almost certainly a serious design flaw. As mentioned there are various container classes to hold multiples of values. If these are distinct in behavior use abstract interfaces, ans store these in a container.

Comment: It would be useful to see the class which these members belong

Comment: I agree with what @user3528438 says. You can create a special class containing both m_jet_pt and h_jet_pt for a single particle type and handle the different flawors in any class container, like vector<jet_class> or any specialization of that, for include extra options. This approach allows to change the set without need for recompile. The container class can carry the control of the set and define the user interface.

Comment: Here is the header of the legacy code I inherited from previous analysis, its pretty bad thus my question for ideas on how to rewrite it:  [link](http://pastebin.com/4bHFFAH6) while here: [link](http://pastebin.com/DhPWm16P) is an example of my attempt to rewrite it. I will have a look on container classes and abstract interfaces as I don't have perfectly clear how I could design such code to do what I need!

Comment: I also agree with making jet-like data a class. Maybe you need to do some overriding for execute and finalize methods.

Comment: Will I need to write getters for all the variables then?

Answer (score 0):

ROOT has a pretty decent I/O functionality and supports reading and writing of arbitrary data structures from/to TTree's. Usually all you need to do is to write a class with data structure corresponding to your single "measurement" or "event". It is up to you how you organize the multiple physical quantities in such class. The structure could be flat with 200 data members at the same level or contain encapsulated non-POD data members of some other class type. The good thing is that ROOT can work well with all different types including scalars, arrays, pointers, and stl containers as data members.

Once you create an object of your class it can be associated with a top-level branch on a TTree as:

```
tree->Branch(branchname, className, &p_object, bufsize, splitlevel)
```

For details see Case B at: https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTTree.html

If you generate dictionary and streamers for all your data structures ROOT will create sub-branches automatically saving you lots of manual work. After that you can use the TTree's methods such as Fill() and GetEntry() to either create an entry by saving your object in the tree or reading values from the tree to your object.